# Can't get my code to work within glob loop?

Tags: excel, replace, glob, xlwings

I have to update 1 particular cell value of the same sheet, from about 600 .xls files. Using `xlwings` library i have been able to replace values of a cell on a sheet and save 1 workbook. I now need to use a code to grab all 600 of my .xls files and run the same replace function to update the cell value.

using `xlwings`, i was able to replace string values very simply:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('Files/firstexcel.xls')
sht1 = wb.sheets['Voucher']
 sht1.range('N5').value = sht1.range('N5').value.replace('phone numbers: phonenumber1 phonenumber2, phonenumber3, phonoenumber4', 'phone number: newnumberX')
 sht1.range('N5').value
```

and this printed:

```
phone number: newnumberX
```

By using glob, I am able to pull files in a directory that end in .xls, and i hope to be able to write onto each of these files using a forloop and xlwings.

```
import os
import glob
import xlwings as xw

os.chdir(r'Files/firstexcel.xls')

for FileList in glob.glob('*.xls'):
    for file in FileList:
        wb = xw.Book(file)
        sht1 = wb.sheets['Voucher']
        sht1.range('N5').value = sht1.range('N5').value.replace('phone numbers: phonenumber1 phonenumber2, phonenumber3, phonoenumber4', 'phone number: newnumberX')
sht1.range('N5').value
        wb.save()
```

and i get this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-36-ff41afc16cc1>", line 13
    wb.save()
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I had expected for the loop to pull those files into a list (FileList) and from Filelist, pull each file and open up their workbook & sheets and modify using the .replace function. But I recieved the indentationerror. Which is trivial, maybe someone can help me clean my code so I can update my files? THANK YOU! :-)

Comment: Check for tabs in your code.

Comment: i only have been using tab to indent and all the indents are the same space. There must be something else this code is missing